# Wordpress needs FTP credentials

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, file-upload, ftp

I install Wordpress 4.3 on my Apache 2.4 but there is a **problem when I want to upload themes, install plugins or updates** :

"*Wordpress needs to access your web server. Please enter your ftp credentials to proceed*"

- I test to create a simple file upload php script, seems work... with
  good temp directory.
- I check **suexec** but seems it's good : apache deamon run with the same user of filse owner.

So I don't know what to do... I post my **phpinfo** and my **vhost** config here.

**Does you have any idea, or have the same issue ?**

VHOST :

```
<Directory /var/www/my-site.com>
        AllowOverride None
                Require all denied
        </Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
                    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site.com/web

        ServerName my-site.com
        ServerAlias www.my-site.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@my-site.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/my-site.com/error.log

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        </IfModule>

        <Directory /var/www/my-site.com/web>
                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                        SetHandler None
                </FilesMatch>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web>
                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                        SetHandler None
                </FilesMatch>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>

        # suexec enabled
        <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
            SuexecUserGroup web2 client0
        </IfModule>
        # php as fast-cgi enabled
    # For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html
        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                IdleTimeout 300
                ProcessLifeTime 3600
                # MaxProcessCount 1000
                DefaultMinClassProcessCount 0
                DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 100
                IPCConnectTimeout 3
                IPCCommTimeout 600
                BusyTimeout 3600
        </IfModule>
        <Directory /var/www/my-site.com/web>
                <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                    SetHandler fcgid-script
                </FilesMatch>
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
                Options +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web>
                <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                    SetHandler fcgid-script
                </FilesMatch>
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
                Options +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>


        # add support for apache mpm_itk
        <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
            AssignUserId web2 client0
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

PHPINFO() :

```
System  Linux vps197951.ovh.net 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64
Build Date  Aug 16 2015 12:16:30
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/cgi
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-imagick.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-imap.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-intl.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-memcache.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-memcached.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-pspell.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-recode.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-tidy.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-xcache.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
PHP API 20131106
PHP Extension   20131226
Zend Extension  220131226
Zend Extension Build    API220131226,NTS
PHP Extension Build API20131226,NTS
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  enabled

Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support  enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0
bz2

BZip2 Support   Enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support   bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version   1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
calendar

Calendar support    enabled
cgi-fcgi

Directive   Local Value Master Value
cgi.check_shebang_line  1   1
cgi.discard_path    0   0
cgi.fix_pathinfo    1   1
cgi.force_redirect  1   1
cgi.nph 0   0
cgi.redirect_status_env no value    no value
cgi.rfc2616_headers 0   0
fastcgi.logging 1   1
Core

PHP Version 5.6.12-0+deb8u1
Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   0   0
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset UTF-8   UTF-8
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,    pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
display_errors  Off Off
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 22527   22527
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  Off Off
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php5/20131226  /usr/lib/php5/20131226
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
input_encoding  no value    no value
internal_encoding   no value    no value
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  60  60
max_file_uploads    64  64
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    512M    512M
open_basedir    /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web:/var/www/clients/client0/web2/private:/var/www/clients/client0/web2/tmp:/var/www/tsara-autisme.com/web:/srv/www/tsara-autisme.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin   /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web:/var/www/clients/client0/web2/private:/var/www/clients/client0/web2/tmp:/var/www/tsara-autisme.com/web:/srv/www/tsara-autisme.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_encoding no value    no value
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   128M    128M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fwebmaster@tsara-autisme.com  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fwebmaster@tsara-autisme.com
serialize_precision 17  17
short_open_tag  Off Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
sys_temp_dir    no value    no value
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 128M    128M
upload_tmp_dir  /var/www/clients/client0/web2/tmp   /var/www/clients/client0/web2/tmp
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.detect_unicode On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value
ctype

ctype functions enabled
curl

cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.38.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  Yes
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL Yes
SSPI    No
TLS-SRP Yes
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1k
ZLib Version    1.2.8
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.3
date

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Berlin
Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value
dba

DBA support enabled
libdb header version    Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (September 9, 2013)
libdb library version   Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (September 9, 2013)
Supported handlers  cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile qdbm
Directive   Local Value Master Value
dba.default_handler flatfile    flatfile
dom

DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.9.1
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
ereg

Regex Library   Bundled library enabled

fileinfo

fileinfo support    enabled
version 1.0.5
libmagic    517
filter

Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Id: 86120bba568c551914a35636ec408f1e7e66af32 $
Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value
ftp

FTP support enabled
gd

GD Support  enabled
GD headers Version  2.1.1-dev
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.5.2
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 6b
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.50
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled
WebP Support    enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
gettext

GetText Support enabled

iconv

iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    glibc
iconv library version   2.19
Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    no value    no value
iconv.internal_encoding no value    no value
iconv.output_encoding   no value    no value

imap

IMAP c-Client Version   2007f
SSL Support enabled
Kerberos Support    enabled
intl

Internationalization support    enabled
version 1.1.0
ICU version 52.1
ICU Data version    52.1
Directive   Local Value Master Value
intl.default_locale no value    no value
intl.error_level    0   0
intl.use_exceptions 0   0
json

json support    enabled
json version    1.3.6
JSON-C headers version  0.11.99
JSON-C library version  0.11.99
libxml

libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version 2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version   20901
libXML streams  enabled
mbstring

Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2
mbstring extension makes ...
Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version 5.9.5
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input no value    no value
mbstring.http_output    no value    no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value
mcrypt

mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version 2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
Supported modes cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value
memcache

memcache support    enabled
Version 3.0.8
Revision    $Revision: 329835 $
Directive   Local Value Master Value
memcache.allow_failover 1   1
memcache.chunk_size 32768   32768
memcache.compress_threshold 20000   20000
memcache.default_port   11211   11211
memcache.hash_function  crc32   crc32
memcache.hash_strategy  consistent  consistent
memcache.lock_timeout   15  15
memcache.max_failover_attempts  20  20
memcache.protocol   ascii   ascii
memcache.redundancy 1   1
memcache.session_redundancy 2   2
memcached

memcached support   enabled
Version 2.2.0
libmemcached version    1.0.18
SASL support    yes
Session support yes
igbinary support    no
json support    no
msgpack support no
Directive   Local Value Master Value
memcached.compression_factor    1.3 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold 2000    2000
memcached.compression_type  fastlz  fastlz
memcached.serializer    php php
memcached.sess_binary   0   0
memcached.sess_connect_timeout  1000    1000
memcached.sess_consistent_hash  0   0
memcached.sess_lock_expire  0   0
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait    0   0
memcached.sess_lock_wait    150000  150000
memcached.sess_locking  1   1
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas   0   0
memcached.sess_prefix   memc.sess.key.  memc.sess.key.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read   0   0
memcached.sess_remove_failed    0   0
memcached.sess_sasl_password    no value    no value
memcached.sess_sasl_username    no value    no value
memcached.store_retry_count 2   2
memcached.use_sasl  0   0
mhash

MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support
mysql

MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.5.44
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external
MYSQL_SOCKET    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off
mysqli

MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.5.44
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.5.43
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink Off Off
openssl

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
Directive   Local Value Master Value
openssl.cafile  no value    no value
openssl.capath  no value    no value
pcntl

pcntl support   enabled
pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.35 2014-04-04
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000
PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite
pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  5.5.44
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.8.7.1
Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.2
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: 72d7e004b07d106bb1ef7c5663a186cbae621385 $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives enabled
ZIP-based phar archives enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   enabled
OpenSSL support enabled
Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On
posix

Revision    $Id: 5d20de77687b7d961b15450873fa23b9e64a136a $
pspell

PSpell Support  enabled
readline

Readline Support    enabled
Readline library    EditLine wrapper
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cli.pager   no value    no value
cli.prompt  \b \>   \b \> 
recode

Recode Support  enabled
Revision    $Id: d95ffdf43fdab6078875dc99d333da459d8d8cd6 $
Reflection

Reflection  enabled
Version $Id: eff8bdc65b0beaf8f4ade6f06f848e6d43dfd826 $
session

Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user memcache memcached
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/www/clients/client0/web2/tmp   /var/www/clients/client0/web2/tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
shmop

shmop support   enabled
SimpleXML

Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: 6b8e23a01a85046737ef7d31346da5164505c179 $
Schema support  enabled
soap

Soap Client enabled
Soap Server enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400
sockets

Sockets Support enabled

sqlite3

SQLite3 support enabled
SQLite3 module version  0.7-dev
SQLite Library  3.8.7.1
Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir   no value    no value
standard

Dynamic Library Support enabled
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fwebmaster@my-site.com
Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent  no value    no value
sysvmsg

sysvmsg support enabled
Revision    $Id: $
tidy

Tidy support    enabled
libTidy Release 25 March 2009
Extension Version   2.0 ($Id: $)
Directive   Local Value Master Value
tidy.clean_output   no value    no value
tidy.default_config no value    no value
tokenizer

Tokenizer Support   enabled
wddx

WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer enabled
XCache

XCache Version  3.2.0
Modules Built   cacher optimizer coverager assembler encoder decoder
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xcache.coredump_directory   no value    no value
xcache.disable_on_crash Off Off
xcache.experimental Off Off
xcache.test Off Off
XCache Cacher

XCache Cacher Module    enabled
Readonly Protection disabled
Page Request Time   2015-09-10 22:38:44
Cache Init Time 2015-09-10 22:35:33
Cache Instance Id   11406
Opcode Cache    enabled, 62,914,560 bytes, 1 split(s), with 8192 slots each
Variable Cache  enabled, 4,194,304 bytes, 1 split(s), with 8192 slots each
Shared Memory Schemes   mmap
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xcache.admin.enable_auth    On  On
xcache.allocator    bestfit bestfit
xcache.cacher   On  On
xcache.count    1   1
xcache.gc_interval  0   0
xcache.mmap_path    /dev/zero   /dev/zero
xcache.readonly_protection  Off Off
xcache.shm_scheme   mmap    mmap
xcache.size 60M 60M
xcache.slots    8K  8K
xcache.stat On  On
xcache.ttl  0   0
xcache.var_allocator    bestfit bestfit
xcache.var_count    1   1
xcache.var_gc_interval  300 300
xcache.var_maxttl   0   0
xcache.var_namespace    no value    no value
xcache.var_namespace_mode   0   0
xcache.var_size 4M  4M
xcache.var_slots    8K  8K
xcache.var_ttl  0   0
XCache Coverager

XCache Coverager Module enabled
Coverage Started    Off
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xcache.coveragedump_directory   no value    no value
xcache.coverager    Off Off
xcache.coverager_autostart  On  On
XCache Optimizer

XCache Optimizer Module enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xcache.optimizer    Off Off
xml

XML Support active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version 2.9.1
xmlreader

XMLReader   enabled
xmlrpc

core library version    xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51
php extension version   0.51
author  Dan Libby
homepage    http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by Epinions.com
xmlwriter

XMLWriter   enabled
xsl

XSL enabled
libxslt Version 1.1.28
libxslt compiled against libxml Version 2.9.2
EXSLT   enabled
libexslt Version    1.1.28
Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Enabled
Startup OK
Shared memory model mmap
Cache hits  0
Cache misses    123
Used memory 19635872
Free memory 47472992
Wasted memory   0
Interned Strings Used memory    2490192
Interned Strings Free memory    1704112
Cached scripts  123
Cached keys 127
Max keys    3907
OOM restarts    0
Hash keys restarts  0
Manual restarts 0
Directive   Local Value Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename  no value    no value
opcache.consistency_checks  0   0
opcache.dups_fix    Off Off
opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off Off
opcache.error_log   no value    no value
opcache.fast_shutdown   0   0
opcache.file_update_protection  2   2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180 180
opcache.inherited_hack  On  On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 4   4
opcache.load_comments   1   1
opcache.log_verbosity_level 1   1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   2000    2000
opcache.max_file_size   0   0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5   5
opcache.memory_consumption  64  64
opcache.optimization_level  0xFFFFFFFF  0xFFFFFFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value    no value
opcache.protect_memory  0   0
opcache.restrict_api    no value    no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
opcache.revalidate_path Off Off
opcache.save_comments   1   1
opcache.use_cwd On  On
opcache.validate_timestamps On  On
zip

Zip enabled
Extension Version   $Id: $
Zip version 1.12.5
Libzip version  0.11.2
zlib

ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.8
Linked Version  1.2.8
Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value
Additional Modules

Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm
Environment

Variable    Value
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS   5000
PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT   /var/www/clients/client0/web2
PATH    /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PHPRC   /etc/php5/cgi/
PWD /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2
PHP Variables

Variable    Value

_SERVER["PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS"]    5000
_SERVER["PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /var/www/clients/client0/web2
_SERVER["PATH"] /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_SERVER["PHPRC"]    /etc/php5/cgi/
_SERVER["PWD"]  /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2
_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]   0
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /phpinfo/index.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /phpinfo/
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  63871
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /var/www/my-site.com/web/phpinfo.php
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] webmaster@my-site.com
_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /var/www/my-site.com/web
_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]   no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]   http
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /var/www/my-site.com/web
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  193.155.155.155
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  149.155.155.155
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  www.my-site.com
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] <address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at www.my-site.com Port 80</address>

_SERVER["HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH"]   "a6-51f6a22c0a06e"

_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]   max-age=0
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  close
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    www.my-site.com
_SERVER["FCGI_ROLE"]    RESPONDER
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /phpinfo/index.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]   1441917524.2893
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1441917524
```

SCREEN OF MESSAGE ERROR :
[image]

Comment: Uh... FTP is something totally separate from anything you've posted. You'll have to install a FTP server to do what you're talking about

Comment: There is an FTP server :) The problem is when you want to make some action like... upload a theme zip.

Comment: set folder to 755 and files to 644, check your apache default user and group and make sure the same user and group is used on your wordpress directory, it is mostly related to user and group

Comment: also check your FastCGI or whatever php processor you use to have the same user as wordpress directory, I encountered same problem on nginx and the problem was the user and group define on socket is different from user and group I use on wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very interested point : everything about right/owner on file and deamon user runner seems correct.
I Precise that come on a VPS Debian 8 managed with **ISPconfig 3.0.3** with apache 2.4, fast-cgi and other mods installed... really strange other users seems have same problem with **ISPconfig 3.0.3**.

Seems `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` inside **wp-config.php** solve the problem. THANKS ! But no logic explanation for me...

Comment: Curious if there are any security implications in using this method, especially in a shared server environment?  Also, within a Zend server environment?

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to any reason on different levels. However I see you have tried almost all correct steps.

You may give this one a try. I used to have same issue on my Ubuntu install of any Wordpress on my local server. And it have always solved the issue.

In your **wp-config.php** file add this line:

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a  permission problem.
change ownership into www-data.www-data for /var/www/html ,and file mode as 755.

```
sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/html
sudo chmod  755  /var/www/html
```

Comment: Please comment, that you are doing with these lines. `Low Quality` answer!